# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type because the type requires a JSON array

Tags: xamarin

My api get json data like this

```
 Office "دكتور نيوترشن"
officename  "11111111"
 address_user   "سيتي مول"
profile_photo   "profile_photo.png"
cover_photo "cover_photo.jpg"
agentarea   "القطيف"
offertext   "قريبا سوف توضح المصومات"
websiteurl  "albatool-hdo"
```

and in xamarin android I am creating this class

```
    public class Galeri
   {
    public Galeri()
    {
    }


    public string Office { get; set; }
    public string officename { get; set; }
    public string address_user { get; set; }
    public string profile_photo { get; set; }
    public string cover_photo { get; set; }
    public string agentarea { get; set; }
    public string offertext { get; set; }
    public string websiteurl { get; set; }
    public string membertype { get; set; }

}
```

and also I am using this code to deserialized json

```
        RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            itemGaleri = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Galeri>>(e.Result);
            CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, itemGaleri);
            DaftarGaleri.Adapter = adapter;
            progress.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            DaftarGaleri.ItemClick += DaftarGaleri_ItemClick;

        }
        );
```

but Iam getting an error

```
    Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})        into type '' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to  deserialize correctly.
```

Comment: Please show the json it self - 'e.Result'

Comment: thank you.. please can you explain more what should i do, I am new

Comment: Your e.Result contains a string, which should represent a json that you should share with us in order to check if your data structure matches the json format.

Comment: you can check my json in browser using this link   http://lifecareclub.net/api/test.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time when you have to deal with JSON and you want to quickly generate the C# models use services like https://app.quicktype.io. Now just give a logical names to your properties like `Galeri` instead of `Welcome`.

```
// To parse this JSON data, add NuGet 'Newtonsoft.Json' then do:
//
//    using QuickType;
//
//    var data = Welcome.FromJson(jsonString);

namespace QuickType
{
    using System;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using Newtonsoft.Json;

    public partial class Welcome
    {
        [JsonProperty("Office")]
        public string Office { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("officename")]
        public string Officename { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("address_user")]
        public string AddressUser { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("profile_photo")]
        public string ProfilePhoto { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("cover_photo")]
        public string CoverPhoto { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("agentarea")]
        public string Agentarea { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("offertext")]
        public string Offertext { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("websiteurl")]
        public string Websiteurl { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("membertype")]
        public string Membertype { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Welcome
    {
        public static Welcome[] FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Welcome[]>(json, Converter.Settings);
    }

    public static class Serialize
    {
        public static string ToJson(this Welcome[] self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, Converter.Settings);
    }

    public class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
        };
    }
}
```